# How to implement different layouts without re-rendering components in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a main component that defines layout of the application, and it uses `router-outlet` to render component depending on current route.

I have completely different layouts for mobile and desktop screen sizes. Here is the simplified version of it:

```
<div *ngIf="isMobile$ | async; else desktopLayoutTemplate">
  <app-mobile-topbar></app-mobile-topbar>
  <app-mobile-sidebar></app-mobile-sidebar>
  <div class="mobile-content-wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #desktopLayoutTemplate>
  <app-desktop-topbar></app-desktop-topbar>
  <app-desktop-sidebar></app-desktop-sidebar>
  <div class="desktop-content-wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

This works fine, but it has one drawback. When I change screen size, and layout switches from desktop to mobile (or vice versa), current page gets re-rendered, because I have 2 different router-outlets, one for each layout. This causes application to fetch data it already loaded.

Is there a way to reuse the current instance of component that is rendered inside router-outlet, when switching layouts.

I know I could achieve this with one layout (and one `router-outlet`) and add classes depending on the value of `isMobile$`, but it becomes really messy.

Is it possible to do something like this in Angular at all?

Comment: Point of clarification - you don't care if it gets re-rendered, what you actually care about, is that you don't refetch data

Comment: I have some pages that can take some time to render (for example page that displays pdf file). So I would like to not do that if possible, but just skipping data re-fetching would also be an improvement

Comment: Potential idea: Just use media queries?

Comment: Yeah, that's the easiest solution, but code becomes really hard to reason about with all the different classes, animations, and elements conditionally displayed. I was just curious if it can be done in some more elegant way.

Comment: This should not be a concern. An end-user is not changing their screen from mobile to desktop. Also, you may be shooting yourself in the foot by creating "desktop" and "mobile" components. If one component is a distinctly compact version of the other, that's fine, call it `my-component-compact`. But if a component is just being responsive, that should be captured in the same component and handled by css. If you absolutely need to keep doing things this way, you will need to find a way to reuse your already declared router-outlet, instead of declaring it twice.